# BGE: Add animated object from empty object that plays at wrong position

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I put the:

1a. Simple animation of a cube that moves forward and backward on layer 2.

1b. Logic brick I set always sensor to action actuator.

1c. Placed on x,y: -4,-5

2a. An empty object (any kind) on layer 1.

2b. Logic brick I set always sensor to edit object > add object > cube from layer two.

2c. Placed on x,y: 3,5

Sorry I cant put screenshot or gif or blend file for easier understanding above.

So, from layer 1, when I hit play, the cube is played in wrong position ! The cube just plays on same position from layer 2 ! It should be positioned to where empty object is added.

Even if I:

1. Parent both of the object
2. Clicked the 'add' from action actuator of the cube on logic brick
3. Or clicked the 'force' <<< this works but it doesn't play the animation
4. Applied location (by shift + a) the cube <<< this works but the origin is wrong placed, I want use this for collision
5. Using animated with armature applied to cube

Still doesn't works… Are I'm doing something wrong or missing ??? I'm desperate and I wouldn't ask to this if I could find the right solution. Any solution and even with  python,would highly appreciated. Please note that I'm very noob at this. I can't Googling with the right keyword. Help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your scene based on your description. If you look closely, the cube spawns in the correct location for one frame, and then the animation forces it back because it is being animated in global space.

In layer 2, add a new empty at the center of the cube. Let's call this empty *CubeAnchor*. Now parent the cube to the *CubeAnchor.* This will make the cube animate in the *CubeAnchor's* local coordinate system.

Lastly, in layer 1 on your empty spawner, Spawn the *CubeAnchor* instead of the cube. The *CubeAnchor's* children will spawn with it, including your animated cube.

Comment: It works ! Yeah ! Its so simple to solve it ! Ugh.... Many thanks! Accepted.

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^